# Ajax based username availability check

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Anyone have examples for creating a new user registration form where the web application checks for username availability via making an ajax call on the form and returning available or not on the same page without a full page post? Something similar to new user registration on Hotmail.

Comment: Yeah, that first guy was quite harsh.

Comment: What language are you implementing this in, everyone seems to be assuming your using .NET / ASP.NET Membership...

Comment: @redsquare: yes... -5, nuff said alrite!