# Ajax Security Question: Supplying Available usernames dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, dynamic, lookup

I am designing a simple registration form in ASP.net MVC 1.0
I want to allow the username to be validated while the user is typing (as per the related questions linked to below)

This is all easy enough.  **But what are the security implications of such a feature?**

**How do i avoid abuse from people scraping this to determine the list of valid usernames?**

some related questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298557/ajax-based-username-availability-check), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577231/live-username-lookup-with-ajax-jquery)

Comment: Is it fair to say that exposing this information regardless of security methods someone determined to get the usernames via abusing this method will eventually get them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent against "malicious" activities on some of my internal ajax stuff, I add two GET variables one is the date (usually in epoch) then I take that date add a salt and SHA1 it, and also post that, if the date (when rehashed) does not match the hash then I drop the request otherwise fulfill it.

Of course I do the encryption before the page is rendered and pass the hash & date to the JS.  Otherwise it would be meaningless.

The problem with using IP/cookie based limits is that both can be bypassed.
Using a token method with a good, cryptographically strong, salt (say something like one of Steve Gibson's "Perfect Passwords" https://www.grc.com/passwords.htm ) it would take a HUGE amount of time (on the scale of decades) before the method could reliably be predicted and there for ensures a certain amount security.

Comment: This was my first thought as well.  a security token

Comment: From my experience this is the most effective way, and it wont bother the users.

Comment: this simply don't works! The hacker can replay the security token unless you use some database solution

Comment: VP there is an assumption that I didn't state in the post, one must check the time, against the current time.

Answer (score 0):

you could limit the number of requests to maybe 2 per 10 seconds or so (a real user may put in a name that is taken and modify it a bit and try again). kind of like how SO doesn't let you comment more than once every 30 seconds.

if you're really worried about it, you could take a method above and count how many times they tried in a certain time period, and if it goes above a threshold, kick them to another page.

Comment: I was considering a security 'token' that needs to be in the request
the token is good for xx number of queries

Comment: Perhaps limiting the number of queries per IP address is a better way to go

Comment: you could go through all the mess of tokens and hashing and whatnot, but i personally believe limiting requests per IP is easier and just as effective, especially if you're not requiring "enterprise level" security

Comment: @jason I attempted to signup at a website recently and within one minute had gone through about 15 names, none of which were valid, I don't think that IP limiting is worth it either users will become frustrated if they cant find a name and cant continue to try, hashing is simple and effective, assuming they don't know your salt, they cannot check names without being on your website.

Comment: @unkwntech - if you are a real person, you probably can't check more than 2 names every 10 seconds anyways. if you are a computer, you can send hundreds of requests in one second. if you really want to split hairs, go for 3 requests in 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Validated as in: "This username is already taken"? If you limit the number of requests per second it should help

Answer (score 0):

One common way to solve this is simply by adding a delay in the request. If the request is sent to the server, wait 1 (or more) seconds to respond, then respond with the result (if the name is valid or not).

Adding a time barrier doesn't really effect users not trying to scrape, and you have gotten a 60-requests per minute limit for free.

Answer (score 0):

Bulding on the answer provided by UnkwnTech, which is some pretty solid advice.

You could go a step further and make the client perform some of calculation to create the return hash - this could just be some simple arithmatic like subtrating a few numbers, adding the data and multiplying by 2.

The added arithmatic does mean an out-of-box username scraping script is unlikely to work and forces the client into using up greater CPU.